# Buscar pedidos entre dos fechas

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy generando un prototipo de una página de pedidos, unos de los datos del pedido es la fecha la cual de ingreso, la cual obtengo de la siguiente manera en string

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //Enero es 0!

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd;
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

console.log(today);
```

Y lo agrego a una tabla de la siguiente manera

```
function mostrarListaPedidos(){
    $("#listaDePedidos").empty();
    var tabla="<table border='2px'>"
        tabla+="<tr><th>Número</th><th>Cliente</th><th>Dirección</th><th>Teléfono</th><th>Fecha de alta</th><th>Plato</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Precio unitario</th><th>Estado</th><th>Precio total</th></tr>"
        for (var i=0;i<arregloPedidos.length;i++) {
            var pedido=arregloPedidos[i];
            var fila="<tr><td>"+pedido.numero+"</td><td>"+pedido.cliente+"</td><td>"+pedido.direccion+"</td><td>"+pedido.telefono+"</td><td>"+pedido.fechaDeAlta+"</td><td>"+pedido.plato+"</td><td>"+pedido.cantidad+"</td><td>$"+pedido.precioUnitario+"</td><td style='font-style: oblique;'>"+pedido.estado+"</td><td>$"+pedido.precioTotal+"</td></tr>"
            tabla+=fila
        }
        tabla+="</table>" 
        $("#listaDePedidos").append(tabla);
}
```

Lo que necesito hacer es poner dos inputs de tipo date donde se pueda elejir una fecha inicial y otra final, y buscar todos los pedidos entre esas dos fechas ingresadas, no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo por eso pregunto sin haber intentado hacer un código!

Comment: Buenas JuanP, entiendo lo que dices de no haber intentado por no tener ni idea, pero investiga, busca algun ejemplo que haga algo parecido e intenta implementarlo. Cualquier cosa sobre la que poder basarnos y ayudarte en tu problema. Añade el HTML y lo necesario para que podamos ver el funcionamiento de tu pagina de pedidos. No olvides pasar por el [tour] y [ask] para aprnder más del sitio y como hacer prguntas de calidad. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Hey amigo pues mira escoje dos controles pues de tipo date claro esta valida que la fecha inicial no sea mayor a la final, teniendo esa validacion luego valida que elija una fecha al darle buscar y como tal el consultar tendrias que ir con el javascript y hacer lo mismo cuando insertar el html.

```
 for (var i=0;i<arregloPedidos.length;i++) {
        var pedido=arregloPedidos[i];
       if( pedido.fecha => 'fecha inicial que viene' && pedido.fecha <= 'fecha final'){
           guardas esos valores en otro arreglo y construyes el html como ya sabes hacerlo.
       }

    }
```

Comment: Disculpa la tardía respuesta y mi poco conocimiento, pero, ¿cómo puedo evaluar si una fecha es menor a otra siendo estas solamente textos? Ya que como dije en la pregunta mis fechas están de la siguiente manera "AAAA-MM-DD"

Comment: Amigos las dos fechas deben estar valga la redundancia en formato fecha osea date para que puedas compararlaa por que en cadena de texto no funcionara

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude hacerlo!